# Fixing the Google API PHP client on hosting service

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

I am using Google API's PHP Client to access gmail contacts. My code is working fine in localhost but it stopped working when I moved it to hosting service. Yes I did verify all the oauth parameters and updated the same in Google API console too.
Is there a way to debug it? I am using codeigniter 2.1.

1. config.php - `$config['uri_protocol']= 'AUTO';`
   and in controller method add `parse_str(substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"), 1), $_GET);` before if condition.
2. Then from [blog][1]. config.php - `$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";` and controller method with `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);` before if condiion.

Controller Method is

```
function gmail_invite()
{
session_start();
$gmailContacts = array();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('tets');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
$client->setClientId('222222.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://testsite.com/gmail_invite');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=500");
  $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
  $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
  //print "<pre>" .print_r($result,false). "</pre>";
  foreach ($result as $title) {
    array_push($gmailContacts, mysql_real_escape_string($title->attributes()->address));
  }
  // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
  //$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));

  //print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {

  redirect($client->createAuthUrl());
}
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';


$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;


$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';


$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$config['cache_path'] = '';

$config['encryption_key'] = '';

$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;

$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
```

Comment: Regarding the `session_start()` issue it is likely you have [session.auto_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) enabled on localhost and not on the production server.

Comment: @crypticツ I have updated my question. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You say your localhost copy is working still, right? If so please upload a fresh copy of it to server. If the app still does not work, then do a `phpinfo();` for both localhost and server and compare the settings and environment variables in `$_SERVER` to see what is different.